# Prove modular inequalities $ab + ac\le a(b+ac)$ and $(a+b)(a+c)\ge a+b(a+c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

How to prove

$$(a\cdot b)+(a\cdot c)\le a\cdot\big(b+(a\cdot c)\big)$$

and

$$(a+b)\cdot(a+c)\ge a+\big(b\cdot(a+c)\big)\;?$$

I have tried this. Using distributive property, I think we can get

$$a+(b\cdot c) \le (a+b)\cdot(a+c)$$

and

$$a\cdot(b+c) \ge (a\cdot b) + (a\cdot c)\;.$$

Now what should I do?

Comment: VISIT http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to write in LATEX

Comment: thanks. I will take a look..

Comment: @Shobhit Can u answer the question?

Comment: What are your operations? I can't shake the feeling that here $\cdot$ and $+$ are supposed to be lattice operations on positive integers, so one is the $\gcd$ and the other $\operatorname{lcm}$, and $\le$ means "divides". So "modular" is in terms of [Modular lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice)??

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are interested in lattice operations on positive integers, so $*$ stands for the greatest common divisor and $+$ for the least common multiple.
By uniqueness of factorization it suffices to do this one prime factor at a time.
So let $p$ be any prime, and denote by $\nu_p(n)$ the highest power of $p$ that
divides the positive integer $n$. So $\nu_p(m*n)=\min\{\nu_p(m),\nu_p(n)\}$
and $\nu_p(m+n)=\max\{\nu_p(m),\nu_p(n)\}$.

Let's look at your first inequality. On the left hand side we have
$$
\nu_p((a*b)+(a*c))=\max\{\min\{\nu_p(a),\nu_p(b)\},\min\{\nu_p(a),\nu_p(c)\}\}
$$
and on the r.h.s. we have
$$
\nu_p(a*(b+(a*c)))=\min\{\nu_p(a),\max\{\nu_p(b),\min\{\nu_p(a),\nu_p(c)\}\}\}.
$$
If here $\nu_p(a)$ is $\ge$ than the other two, then both sides simplify to
$\max\{\nu_p(b),\nu_p(c)\}$. If $\nu_p(a)$ is $\le$ than the other two, then both sides simplify to $\nu_p(a)$. If $\nu_p(b)\le\nu_p(a)\le\nu_p(c)$, then
again both sides simplify to $\nu_p(a)$. Also if $\nu_p(c)\le\nu_p(a)\le\nu_p(b)$
both sides still evaluate to $\nu_p(a)$.

Do the other inequality in the same way. This lattice of integers is modular, so you always get equality.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the precondition $a,b,c\geq 1$.
Then
$$ab + ac = a(b+c) = a(b+1\cdot c)\overset{a\geq 1}{\leq} a(b + ac)$$
and
$$(a+b)(a+c) = a\underbrace{(a+c)}_{\geq 1} + b(a+c) \geq a + b(a+c).$$

Comment: Let's wait for the OP to comment. I'm not sure that the operations are what you seem to think they are.